# Office for Mac 2011 - unable to insert cells properly in Excel

Tags: mac, microsoft-excel-2011

I am unable to insert cells in a spreadsheet the way I want to.

When I try to insert two cells, the action automatically defaults to inserting a row instead of shifting cells down or right.

How do I insert cells such that they shift existing cells instead of creating a new row?

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-clicking on a cell and selecting `Insert...` gives you a dialog box with options about how to insert:

[image: context menu, Insert... highlighted]

[image: insert dialog box]

<sub>(yes, this is Windows Excel, but if recollection serves the menus are the same)</sub>

It sounds like you want one of the first two options, `Shift cells right/down`.

Note that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-clicking on a row/column and selecting `Insert` will, by design, insert a new row/column.